# How to install dependencies of lambda functions upon cdk build with AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

When using AWS SAM I used to run `build` command which would go through all of my Lambda function packages and install their dependencies (run `npm install` on them).

How can I achieve the same behavior with AWS CDK? It doesn't seem to do it automatically, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality really is missing. You'll need to write your own packaging. Keep in mind that lambda dependencies must be built on a system with the same architecture as the target system in AWS (Linux) if any of the dependencies (such as Numpy) uses a shared library with native C code.

There's a Docker image available which aims to provide an environment as close to AWS as possible: `lambci/lambda:build-python3.7`

So if you're building on any non-Linux architecture, you might need this for some more complex lambda functions.

EDIT: I opensourced my Python code for lambda packaging: https://gitlab.com/josef.stach/aws-cdk-lambda-asset

Answer (score 12):

You can do this pretty easily with a local build script like this:

```js
    const websiteRedirectFunction = new lambda.Function(
      this,
      "RedirectFunction",
      {
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../redirect"), {
          bundling: {
            command: [
              "bash",
              "-c",
              "npm install && npm run build && cp -rT /asset-input/dist/ /asset-output/",
            ],
            image: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X.bundlingDockerImage,
            user: "root",
          },
        }),
        handler: "index.redirect",
        tracing: lambda.Tracing.ACTIVE,
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
      }
    );
```

Assuming you have a folder that you want to build and upload the handler and node_modules for Lambda.

**From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-lambda-readme.html#bundling-asset-code):**

> When using lambda.Code.fromAsset(path) it is possible to bundle the code by running a command in a Docker container. The asset path will be mounted at /asset-input. The Docker container is responsible for putting content at /asset-output. The content at /asset-output will be zipped and used as Lambda code.

Answer (score 2):

There is (currently experimental) module inside `aws-cdk` which solves the problem for Python.

See more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-lambda-python-readme.html).

Comment: This is still in alpha as far as I can tell, in CDK v2. I tried using it but couldn't work out how to import it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using Python. (until aws-lambda-python lib is [ready](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-lambda-python-alpha-readme.html))

Install the function dependencies directly into the lambda function folder of your CDK project.

```
pip install --target ./ -r ./requirements.txt
```

Requirements text is just a list of dependencies:

```
requests==2.27.1
```

Then run:

```
cdk deploy
```

Everything in the lambda function folder will be deployed:

- Dependencies,
- Function code,
- Requirements.txt, etc.

Some more details here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

Answer (score 0):

It does not do it automatically
You'll need to package those. Then you'll be able to use [fromAsset](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Code.html) or fromBucket to get connect the code to the function

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate project using SAM
put all the requirements in requirements.txt alongside your app.py

then run `sam build --build-dir packaged`
The `packaged` directory will have the packaged artifact with dependencies.

Then all that you have to do in your cdk is
`
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_lambda as lambda_)

.....

```
    lambdaFn = lambda_.Function(
        self, "DocManAuth",
        handler="app.lambda_handler",
        code=lambda_.Code.asset("../auth/packaged/DocManAuthFunction"),
        timeout=core.Duration.seconds(30),
        runtime=lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
    )

    core.CfnOutput(self, 'Authorizer Function',
                   value=lambdaFn.function_name)
```

`

for a complete project visit 
[docman](https://github.com/gauravcj/docman)